# Spring @PropertySource set path dynamically

Tags: java, spring

I am developing Core java application using Spring Core.And this application will work as executable jar.

This application has configuration file which will load using @PropertySource and currently this path set as "class-path:".

I will install this executable jar on different different machine. the executable jar folder path will be different.

I need to put this projectconfig.properties outside the jar file so that user can able to set the configuration as per his requirement. **How can I do this?**

**How i can set path dynamically?**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:com/org/abc/xyz/properties/projectconfig.properties")
public class ProjectConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

public String getProperty(String propName) {
    return env.getProperty(propName);
}   
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey8j9.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using `Spring Boot`? Or if not have you considered using it? https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `@ConfigurationProperties`. `Spring Boot` will load `application.properties` from the start folder or from ./config folder. 
Please read the [externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) chapter from spring boot development guide.